# Issue with Complex data types processing in pig with comma delimited data

Tags: apache-pig

I have the data like this:

```
$ cat samp.txt 
Ramesh,[city#Bangalore],123
Arun,[city#Anantapur],345
Pranith,[city#US],456
```

I have written the following pig query:

```
A = load 'samp.txt' using PigStorage(',')
as(name:chararray,addr:map[chararray,chararray],empno:int);
```

When I execute the above code in pig I am getting the following error:

```
error: mismatched input ',' expecting RIGHT_BRACKET Details at logfile: /home/training/pig_1471586597209.log
```

Can any one help me to resolve this error?

Comment: error: mismatched input ',' expecting RIGHT_BRACKET
    Details at logfile: /home/training/pig_1471586597209.log

Comment: You should edit your question to add the error and reorder elements of your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
A= load 'pdemo/samp' using PigStorage(',') as (name:chararray,add:map[],empno:int);
```

Now it will work..